# Overlapping border with CSS

Tags: css, overlap

I have a webpage header that I am trying to make overlap with a border. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UP7sD/4/) of a simplified version of what I have.
 This is what I am aiming for: (The second row of images is what would happen if the page width is reduced.)

[image]

I tried using absolute positioning of the green (logo), but this causes the menu (yellow) to overlay with the logo instead of vertically stacking on the page like happens now.

My next idea was to give the border (red) absolute positioning, but in various attempts at that I always seemed to end up with the border at the top of the page, like the header div was ignoring the height of the logo/menu. That was set up something like:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
}
#border {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to set this up, either fixing what I have or trying a different approach altogether?

**Edit:**
Here's a better depiction of why I'm trying to do this, using the same colors (why the overlap and why the yellow menu should end up over the logo):
[image]

Comment: I don't see the yellow bit in your jsFiddle..

Comment: I can't see the difference between your images.

Comment: Sorry, linked to a different version of the jsFiddle. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like this?

The green block is overlapped by the red border block.

**Edit -** Added percentage width and `@media` query so it resizes.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/JZgAT/3/)

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
        Contents
    </div>
    <div id="logo"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    min-width: 320px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
}
#logo {
    background: green;
    height: 80px;
    width: 190px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 40px;
}
#menu {    
    height: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    background: yellow;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {    
  #menu {
    top: 30px;
  }
}
#header:after {
    content:'';
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #F00;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, but responsive to different widths.

Comment: But how can I include the menu contents in the `:before`? As far as I can tell, the most you can put in the pseudo-elements is an image (which works for the logo, but not the menu).

Comment: Just replace the `:before` with an actual div like [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZgAT/2/) :)

Comment: Hang on, though - this still doesn't let me have the green and yellow blocks on the same level vertically.

Comment: That's where `@media` comes in. [Resize this fiddle and see the results](http://jsfiddle.net/JZgAT/3/)